# How to use NtQueryInformationByName?

Tags: c++, winapi

I just want to try out the undocumented API: **NtQueryInformationByName**.

Tried following code but only get **STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER**.

OS: Windows 10 1903 18362.145

```
void InternalGetFileInfo()
{
    /* Hide getting function pointer here */

    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes{};
    UNICODE_STRING UnicodeString{};
    WCHAR wszPath[] = L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe";

    if (!_RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U(wszPath, &UnicodeString, NULL, NULL))
    {
        cout << "RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U error=" << GetLastError() << endl;
        return;
    };

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjectAttributes, &UnicodeString, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatus{};
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TAG_INFORMATION TagInfo{};
    NTSTATUS status = _NtQueryInformationByName(&ObjectAttributes, &IoStatus, &TagInfo, sizeof(TagInfo), (FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS)35);

    cout << status << endl;

    _RtlFreeUnicodeString(&UnicodeString);
}
```

Comment: If it's undocumented, you're not supposed to use it.

Comment: @molbdnilo Since there are books and many other resources about undocumented windows functions (think of Wine, Reactos, etc..), this is a legitimate question I would say.

Comment: The error code indicates, that the caller is violating the contract. But there is literally no way to know, what that contract *is*. It isn't documented, after all.

Comment: To make matters worse, we don't even know where the code fails. And if we did, we wouldn't know, whether the error codes are actually meaningful. On top of calling `GetLastError` too late, it's also the wrong API to call; the native API does not report errors by setting the calling thread's last error code.

Comment: `NtQueryInformationByName` support only single `FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS` *FileStatInformation* - for all other returned `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. so you can only query [`FILE_STAT_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_stat_information) with this api

Comment: @RbMm Thanks for this information. It is really useful.